# Is there any full note-map for 4-hole harmonica?

Tags: harmonica

In my opinion; to play a harmonica well, we should know about its full note-map:

[[image: 1]]

---

I am interested in [4-hole harmonica](http://us.playhohner.com/enjoy-music-everywhere/enjoy-music-everywhere-harmonicas/little-lady-standard/); and, I want to play it well. I have searched on Google about the **Tuning chart** of a **4-hole harmonica**; but, there is lite note-map:

```
C6 E6  G6  C7
1   2   3   4
D6  F6  A6  B(H)6
```

Now, I want to ask: "Is there any full note-map for a 4-hole harmonica?".

Answer (score 1):

The 4 hole that you link has the same tuning as holes 4-7 of a standard 10 hole.  That is one full octave.  That's what the tuning chart on your link shows.

The only thing your 10 hole diagram adds are the 2 bends, which lower the note a semitone (Db and Ab).  The usual instructions for producing a bend apply.  So there's a chance that you will be able, with practice, to bend the lowest hole.  On a 10 hole, it is easiet to bend 3 and 4. But your 1st task is to learn to play single notes.

Frankly I think you are better off getting a standard 10 hole harmonica.  Instructions and tabs will assume that.  A 4 hole is a toy.  Spend $30-40 for a 10 hole instead of $15 for this 4 hole.

Take a look at the songs at https://www.harptabs.com/.  You'll have trouble finding songs that just use holes 4-7.

---

Looking again at the 4 hole chart I realize it is from C6 to C7.  That's the range of the upper octave of regular 10 hole C harmonica (C4 to C7).  Mapping that on to the bends of the 10 hole chart, I'm guessing that it will be hard to bend the draws (the Db).  http://www.harpsurgery.com/how-to-play/blow-bends/ doesn't sound very encouraging about mastering a blow-bend in this key either.